# JPA persisting instead of updating

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I came across a strange problem,  whenever I try to edit a register in my application instead of update  the state of the entity, it persists a new one. Here goes my  `update` method

```
public void update(Object obj) {
    EntityManagerFactory fac = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("crud");
    EntityManager em = fac.createEntityManager();
    em.merge(obj);
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    em.close();
    fac.close();
}
```

My guess is when I submit the edit form and the setters are called the `Id` is somehow set to 0. Is that possible to happen ? The form looks like this :

```
<h:form>
                <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin: 0 auto;">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Edit form
                    </f:facet>
                    Name:
                    <h:inputText id="nome" value="#{editUserBean.userToEdit.name}"/>
                    Age:
                    <h:inputText value="#{editUserBean.userToEdit.age}" converter="javax.faces.Integer"/>
                    Pass:
                    <h:inputText value="#{editUserBean.userToEdit.password}"/>
                    Gender:
                    <h:selectOneRadio value="#{editUserBean.userToEdit.gender}" style="font-size: 12px;">
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Masc" itemLabel="Masc" />
                        <f:selectItem itemValue="Fem" itemLabel="Fem" />
                    </h:selectOneRadio>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <div align="center">
                            <h:commandButton value="save" actionListener="#{editUserBean.save}" icon="ui-icon-check"/>
                        </div>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

`Hibernate` is querying this :

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        hibernate_sequence.nextval 
    from
        dual
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        users
        (age, gender, name, password, id) 
    values
        (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
```

Comment: Why you are creating entityManager? it should be created once per instance (all sessions goes in static context). Also instead of merge, you just need to persist. EntityManager will map already persisted object and updates it if you added new states to it. But if you create entityManager everytime you want to update, it cannot map your already persisted objects.

Comment: Actually I putted it there for the name of the context, my EntityManager is a global variable

Comment: So you can just create it in static { } block.

Comment: Debug and see if your object has id when calling merge. Your form doesn't have id field in it, so I guess the id is not being passed when submitting.

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly Your tip worked for me ! The problem was that once submitted, the form was setting the id to 0. As expected id == 0 it'll persist everytime. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is in the JSF layer.

All evidence points that `editUserBean` is *request scoped*. Which means that you will get a new bean per request.

So, we are working with a **new** `userToEdit` bean on every request. Its properties will be either `null` or a default value for primitives (e.g., `0` for `int` and `long`), unless you explicitly declared a default value for the property inside the bean. This includes the `id`, which in your case is `0`.

When you merge your bean, there is no entity with id `0` in the persistence context or a respective entry in the database, so `merge` will persist a new entity. If you are generating values for the primary key, odds are that you will never have `0` as an `id`, so the JPA layer will keep persisting new entities.

One simple fix for this problem consists in storing the user information in a bean with a [broader scope](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/cdi-basic008.htm), say *session scoped* or user defined *conversation scoped*:

```
@ConversationScoped
class UserToEdit extends User {
   // ... or if you want, create a HAVE-A relationship
}
```

Then you can inject your bean as usual and the stored `id` will survive between requests (don't forget to clean up; correctly demarcate conversation boundaries and/or clean the session bean).

---

Another workaround - if you absolutely must keep the user info in the *request scope* - is using a hidden field to hold the value of the `id` (as well as any non-editable property that you wish). This way the user `id`  will also be submitted on the next request and the model will be correctly updated.

```
<h:inputHidden value="#{editUserBean.userToEdit.id}" />
```

**Warning:** While this workaround is pretty popular, only do it if the current user is able to update information of any other user. Why? A malicious user can easily manipulate the DOM in order to change the `user.id` and / or submit a fake request containing any `id` to abuse the system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you have already tried this but check the hibernate configuration file...and then may be one of the tag contains the value create. Change it to update. Hope this helps

Comment: Yes try it, probably every time you create EMF you erase the data, be sure config file said validate not create. I think it could be the problem, very good suggestions my friend if it works consider +1

Comment: No, I'm using persistence.xml. The property hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto is set to update

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things... First inject your PersistenceContext like this into your EJB:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;
```

Next, mark your function, or the entire EJB with the proper automatic transaction handling:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class MyServiceEJBThingy {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
```

In your method, don't do anything but your business logic. Transaction sematics are now handled for you automagically:

```
@Stateless
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)
public class MyServiceEJBThingy {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public void update(Object obj) {
        //GUI independent business logic here
        em.merge(obj);
    }
}
```

Finally, now inject your EJB in your view controller (assuming you're using the MVVM pattern):

```
@RequestScoped (or something)
public class EditUserBean {
   @Inject
   private MyServiceEJBThingy myServiceEJBThingy;


   public void update(Object obj) {
       // GUI logic here
       myServiceEJBThingy.update(obj);
   }
}
```

Much simpler yes? :) Java can be very simple and productive. I'm not sure what container you're using, but I'd suggest using Apache TomEE. Check out their huge library of up-to-date examples [here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/index.html). Good luck!!!

Comment: Going to implement that. Thanks

Comment: If it works, don't forget to upvote and/or accept my answer and other people's answers ;) That's how you reward people for helping you out on stackoverflow :)

Comment: oh snap! Well keep coming back :)